# Scale factor where $\ddot{a}=0$ in the benchmark model

Tags: cosmology

Working through Ryden's *Introduction to Cosmology.* The full questions goes as follows

> In the Benchmark Model, at what scale factor $a$ did $\ddot{a}=0$. [This represents the moment when expansion switched from slowing down ($\ddot{a}<0$) to speeding up ($\ddot{a}>0$)] Is this scale factor larger or smaller than the scale factor $a_{m\Lambda}$ at which the energy density of matter equaled the energy density of the cosmological constant?

I know that in an $N$ component universe, the acceleration equation is given by

$$\frac{\ddot{a}}{a}=-\frac{4\pi G}{3c^2} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\varepsilon_i (1+3w_i)$$

The only thing I can think of is rewriting the acceleration equation as
$$\ddot{a}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\varepsilon_i(1+3w_i)=0$$

However, I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Is there information I can extract from this? Or I can I get the scale factor from the energy densities?

Comment: Start with the relationship between Hubble's parameter and energy density, $$H = H_0\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_c + \Omega_b}{a^3}+\Omega},$$ and then from $\Omega_k = 0$ and $w = -1$, expand the equation given, then use $\ddot{a}=0$ (you will also have to use $H = \dot{a}/a$. To know what you are looking for, I got $a \simeq\left(\frac{\Omega_m}{2\Omega_\Lambda}\right)^{1/3} \sim 0.6$.

Comment: I ended up getting the same scale factor. I wrote out my equation for energy densities and then divided by the energy density of matter. The textbook had ratios that wrote energy densities as a function of scale factor and $\Omega$. Thank you!